# Flask and Celery on Heroku: sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (psycopg2.DatabaseError) SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac

Tags: python, heroku, flask, celery, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to deploy a flask app on heroku that uses background tasks in Celery. I've implemented the [application factory pattern](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/appfactories/) so that the celery processes are not bound to any one instance of the flask app.

This works locally, and I have yet to see an error. But when deployed to heroku, the same results always occur: the celery task (I'm only using one) succeeds the first time it is run, but any subsequent celery calls to that task fail with `sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (psycopg2.DatabaseError) SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac`. If I restart the celery worker, the cycle continues.

There are [multiple](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1564) [issues](https://github.com/ui/django-rq/issues/123) that show this same [error](https://github.com/wooey/Wooey/issues/31), but none specify a proper solution. I initially believed implementing the application factory pattern would have prevented this error from manifesting, but it's not quite there.

In `app/__init__.py` I create the celery and db objects:

```
celery = Celery(__name__, broker=Config.CELERY_BROKER_URL)
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])

    db.init_app(app)
    return app
```

My `flask_celery.py` file creates the actual Flask app object:

```
import os
from app import celery, create_app

app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG', 'default'))
app.app_context().push()
```

And I start celery with this command:
`celery worker -A app.flask_celery.celery --loglevel=info`

This is what the actual celery task looks like:

```
@celery.task()
def task_process_stuff(stuff_id):
    stuff = Stuff.query.get(stuff_id)
    stuff.processed = True
    db.session.add(stuff)
    db.session.commit()
    return stuff
```

Which is invoked by:

```
task_process_stuff.apply_async(args=[stuff.id], countdown=10)
```

**Library Versions**

- Flask 0.12.2
- SQLAlchemy 1.1.11
- Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.2
- Celery 4.0.2

Comment: Just to make sure you cannot make any query to the database correct?

Comment: @skagra_dragneel the first time, I can connect to the database and the task works just fine. Any time after that, the task fails right away and no query to the database can be made.

Comment: darn thought i had the solution, had a similar issue, but i couldnt connect to the database at all

Comment: Your celery workers keep reusing the same connection. How about a `db.session.remove()` after you commit a session? It should force the re-establishment of a connection.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I tried adding `db.session.remove()` after the commit, but the error continues.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution was to add `db.engine.dispose()` at the beginning of the task, disposing of all db connections before any work begins:

```
@celery.task()
def task_process_stuff(stuff_id):
    db.engine.dispose()
    stuff = Stuff.query.get(stuff_id)
    stuff.processed = True
    db.session.commit()
    return stuff
```

As I need this functionality across all of my tasks, I added it to `task_prerun`:

```
@task_prerun.connect
def on_task_init(*args, **kwargs):
    db.engine.dispose()
```

Comment: Could anyone explain the root cause of this issue? Why would this affect Celery workers and not Gunicorn workers?

Comment: Hi, I had the same issue and I couldn't find why this is like this? It's a very strange behaviour with celery workers...